# A particle travels at velocity $|t - 1|$ at time $t$.

Tags: calculus

Question: A particle travels at velocity $|t - 1|$ at time $t$. Divide the interval $[0, 2]$ into $2k$ intervals of equal length where $k\in\mathbb{N}$. Find the minimum velocity of the particle on each of these time intervals.

My approach to this question is to experiment with the numbers. For example, if $k = 1$, if $k = 2$, if $k = 3$, etc... And I think that you would have to find the derivative of the velocity of the particle to find the minimum velocity.

But I am not really sure how to approach from here.

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hint

For $t < 1,$ the particle's speed is decreasing, as it approaches $t = 1$, which implies that
you want *which* end of the interval for minimum velocity?

For $t > 1,$ everything is symmetrically the opposite.

No need to take derivatives.